# Developing multiple pages in a dynamic language but need to output to static HTML files?

Tags: php, html, ruby

I'm making website templates where the final product will be static HTML files.

What I'm looking for is something in PHP (or maybe Ruby) that will allow me to develop the pages in that language and then output the files to HTML (with the right structure and names) in a click or command.

Comment: Just put your scripts output into static files. Proxy servers are doing that all day long. Works with any language, you just need to have your scripts accessible via HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need static site generator.

Some examples:

- Ruby: https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll
- Python: http://ringce.com/hyde
- Node.js: http://docpad.org

Answer (score 2):

You want wget :) No, really: make the site in whatever dynamic language you use, and then mirror it with wget - you'll get a complete static version of your site:

> wget -k -r --restrict-file-names=windows http://www.example.com/

which `-r`ecursively downloads the site,
`-k`onverts the links,
and avoids the use of `?` and similar "special" characters in the filenames

This will get you a *completely* static version of your site - note that you want to keep the dynamic version around, in case you need to make changes: then you need to do this conversion again (editing the static version is a major PITA).

Comment: Nice answer. Sadly my pages don't link together for this template but upvote for ingenuity.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you may want for PHP based solution is the smarty templating engine.. http://www.smarty.net/.

A ruby on rails solution would be to use thoughtbot's high voltage rails plugin https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage

Answer (score 0):

Buffer the output, and have a naming scheme for your pages. PHP has functions which let you buffer to a variable which can then be saved - [ob_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).